# How to "save" parameters to \begin{tikzpicture}

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, tikz-styles

I'm new to using tikz and every time I insert a diagram, I paste in the following block (I'm typing up physics homework, so the sorts of pictures I have to draw are pretty much always the same):

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    force/.style={>=latex,draw=blue,fill=blue},
    axis/.style={densely dashed,gray,font=\small},
    M/.style={rectangle,draw,fill=lightgray,minimum size=0.5cm,thin},
    m/.style={rectangle,draw=black,fill=lightgray,minimum size=0.3cm,thin},
    plane/.style={draw=black,fill=blue!10},
    string/.style={draw=red, thick},
    pulley/.style={thick},
]
```

I would like to shorten the command I have to type. My understanding is that those are "styles" and that there is a way to do this, but my attempts using tikzset have only produced confusing results. (Basically, the stuff I wrote in tikzset got output as text on the first page of the document) I would appreciate some help.

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) as always on this site, it is a good idea to post a full minimal example that others can copy and test without having to guess most of the document

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `\tikzset`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{    
    force/.style={>=latex,draw=blue,fill=blue},
    axis/.style={densely dashed,gray,font=\small},
    M/.style={rectangle,draw,fill=lightgray,minimum size=0.5cm,thin},
    m/.style={rectangle,draw=black,fill=lightgray,minimum size=0.3cm,thin},
    plane/.style={draw=black,fill=blue!10},
    string/.style={draw=red, thick},
    pulley/.style={thick},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[pulley] (0,0) -- (1,0);
% more code here
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```